# Nargs='+' capturing too many arguments python

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I am using argparse for command line arguments, where one argument is one or more `.csv` files:

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='...')
parser.add_argument('csv', type=str, nargs='+', help='.csv file(s)'))
parser.add_argument('days', type=int, help='Number of days'))

args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.csv)
```

When running `$ python Filename.py csv Filename.csv days 30`, `args.csv` is `['csv', 'Filename.csv', 'days']`, but I don't want to be capturing the `csv` and `days` arguments which surround the input csv files.

Comment: When you add arguments without the `--` prefix, they become positional arguments. You don't need to write "csv" nor "days" in the command call, their values are defined by their position. `python Filename.py Filename.csv 30` will work as you expect it to

Comment: You have two arguments, the first captures all except the last one. That's expected. What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @GPhilo explained it @a_guest I didn't realise that I didn't need to write ````csv```` and ````days````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='...')
parser.add_argument("csv", type=str, nargs='+', help='.csv file(s)')
parser.add_argument("days", type=int, help='Number of days')

args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.csv)
```

Invoked with e.g. `python your_script.py test.csv 100` this yields

```
['test.csv']
```

Note that you do not need to encapsulate `parser.add_argument(...)` twice (as you had in your code).

Comment: I have edited my question, as I had erroneously copied over my code, I had not made the ````parser.add_argument(parser.add_argument```` error in my original code. The answer is correct but I feel that repeating my code is a bit superfluous? Rather than just adding a comment